# Changing the WandB logging directory

Tags: logging, wandb

I'm doing a lot of experiments with WandB, and it is on a shared server where logs and whatnot need to be placed in specific directories. WandB likes to store a lot of information (as it should, defined by me) so the folder grows rapidly, up to 5GB in a single day.

Is there any way to specify to WandB where to put this folder with logs?.. I searched their docs, but didn't find anything that mentions a parameter in `init` or otherwise to specify the path.

Alternatively, I thought of moving the physical location of the WandB folder from my script path to the proper place, and creating a symlink to my script location. Do you think that would work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting this answer because Google didn't properly index the WandB docs, and it isn't mentioned there sufficiently, so this becomes easier to find for those in the future who may have missed it.

---

The default WandB logging directory is set to `./wandb` which is the default parameter for the `dir` config parameter of `wandb.init` which means you can set `dir="your path"` during `wandb.init`;

Additionally, it is unwise to attempt to create a global `wandb` directory for multiple unrelated runs and symlink all of the runs WandB logs to the one directory due to how WandB handles artifacts.

Comment: When I set e.g. `dir="./outputs/wandb"` the log files are not written to this location but to the OS's tempfile directory. Am I missing anything special that one has to pay attention to? PS: I also tried absolute paths as mentioned in the doctstring.

Comment: I overlooked the warning `Path {path} wasn't writable, using system temp directory` which is caused by https://github.com/wandb/wandb/blob/605dc0ce5ff7eff8ba32d436c8fa83636f8cc42c/wandb/old/core.py#L40-L43. I think, this is caused by missing intermediate directories, since `dir="./outputs/"` worked.

Answer (score 2):

Wandb hosted on server creates volume with name wandb. All logs store into that folder.

```
jetson@nano:~$ docker volume inspect wandb
[
   {
       "CreatedAt": "2023-10-01T15:26:21+02:00",
       "Driver": "local",
       "Labels": null,
       "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/wandb/_data",
       "Name": "wandb",
       "Options": null,
       "Scope": "local"
   }
]
```

You can change it's Mountpoint, or set another volume at "docker run wandb/local" commnad.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, fantastic first answer, thank you for the contribution!